# How to resolve Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository':

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

i've tried to create a microservice to talk with a db, in kotlin. I've added the hibernate and jpa dependency, but when i try to run it i've received the following error :
`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'anagraficaServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository': Error creating bean with name 'anagraficaRepository' defined in com.example.pecoDb.JPA.AnagraficaRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.pecoDb.anagraficaDAO.AnagraficaJpa`

**AnagraficaJPA**

```
package com.pecoDb.anagraficaDAO

import jakarta.persistence.Column
import jakarta.persistence.Entity
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue
import jakarta.persistence.Id
import jakarta.persistence.Table


@Entity
@Table
data class AnagraficaJpa(

    @Column
    val nome: String ,
    @Column
    val cognome: String ,
    @Column
    val dataNascita: String ,
    @Column
    val comune: String ,
    @Column
    val nazionalita: String ,
    @Column
    val provincia: String ,
    @Column
    val indirizzo: String,
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    val idPecoAnagrafica: Long?=null,
)
```

**Anagrafica Repository**

```
package com.example.pecoDb.JPA

import com.pecoDb.anagraficaDAO.AnagraficaJpa
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

interface AnagraficaRepository:CrudRepository<AnagraficaJpa, Long> {
    fun findByname(name: String): AnagraficaJpa
}
```

**POM edit **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>PEcoDb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>blog</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <h2.version>1.4.196</h2.version>
        <hibernate-core.version>5.6.9.Final</hibernate-core.version>
        <hibernate-testing.version>5.6.9.Final</hibernate-testing.version>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <jaxb-api.version>2.3.0</jaxb-api.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.9.22</kotlin.version>
        <kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm.version>1.6.2</kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm.version>
        <kotlinx-serialization-json-jvm.version>1.6.3</kotlinx-serialization-json-jvm.version>
        <ktor_version>2.3.8</ktor_version>
        <mysql-connector-j.version>8.3.0</mysql-connector-j.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
        <springdoc-openapi-ui.version>1.7.0</springdoc-openapi-ui.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-connector-j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

I've try to change from jakarta to javax, and also i've tried to remove column annotation, but the result what the same of that i've write, the error.
How can i resolve it ?
Thanks

Comment: Your package structure is a mess and you are managing too much yourself. Ditch the `hibernate` managing, those are included in `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in the correct version as well. Next fix your packages to share the same base package not a mixture of packages.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry for the mess on my pom, but is the first time that i create a microservice from zero, so you suggest to remove all MySQL and hibernate dependency ? Could you please share me this solution ? Thanks

Comment: Where do you think I state you should remove MySQL dependencies? I state hibernate!, the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` already includes all you need. But the main problem is your package structure not sharing a main base package. Everything should be in the same package as your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class (or a sub package).

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry, but i cannot understand the change you suggest, now I've changed the pom (could you see in the principal question, above). If I'll do some mistake could you show me where  ? thanks

Comment: As stated twice before your packages are a mess (you did read the whole comment didn't you? ) you need to fix that else classes wont' be detected.